# Russia to The Netherlands. What are the implications of changing from a hostel to a private apartment AFTER getting the visa and crossing the border?

Tags: netherlands, hostels, schengen-visas, proof-of-accommodation, vfs-global

I'm going to The Netherlands either by invitation or using tourist visa, depending on if I get the invitation in time.

So in case I'm getting a tourist visa to The Netherlands, am I going to face some charges for changing my accommodation from a hostel to, for example, a friend's apartment (the friend who also sends me the invitation)? Or after receiving the visa can I easily change it without a problem?

Will proof of accommodation from the hostel also work here? The visa center is VFS Global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have received your visa and entered the country, you can freely change your accommodation.

As long as you leave before the terms of your visa expire, you are fine.

During the application process, you have to show proof of accommodation. This is usually by means of a reservation showing your name, and the check-in / check-out dates (which should make sense with the other details of your planned visit).